# Mixing pass-by-reference and pass-by-value to variadic template function valid?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, placement-new

I have a method which allocates memory for a object and then calls its constructor - a memory allocator.

```
template <class T, typename... Arguments>
inline T* AllocateObject(Arguments... args) { return new (InternalAllocate(sizeof(T))) T(args...); }
```

Is it valid using this function to mix pass-by-value and pass-by-reference? For example allocating a class with a constructor with some by-value and some by-reference. It compiles, but I'm not sure if it has any nasty side-effects or not.

Comment: You should probably use `T(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...)`, but besides that you should be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is *perfect forwarding*, ie. your `AllocateObject` function should be completely transparent as far as copying side effects are concerned.

This involves both `std::forward` (as nijansen already mentioned) and the use of *universal references* in your parameter list:

```
template <class T, typename... Arguments>
inline T* AllocateObject(Arguments&&... args)
//                                ^^ universal references
{
    return new (InternalAllocate(sizeof(T))) T(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);
    //                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ forwarding
}
```

Comment: Yeah I did indeed forget `&&`, that's kind of important for perfect forwarding ;)

Comment: Sidenote: Universal References have been renamed to "Forwarding References" by now.