# Template function does not work for pointer-to-member-function taking const ref

Tags: c++, templates

Lately I wrote a template function to solve some code repetitions. It looks like this:

```
template<class T, class R, class... Args>
R call_or_throw(const std::weak_ptr<T>& ptr, const std::string& error, R (T::*fun)(Args...), Args... args) {
    if (auto sp = ptr.lock()) 
    {
        return std::invoke(fun, *sp, args...);
    }
    else 
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(error.c_str());
    }
}

int main() {
    auto a = std::make_shared<A>();
    call_or_throw(std::weak_ptr<A>(a), "err", &A::foo, 1);
}
```

This code works perfectly well for `class A` which looks like this:

```
class A {
public:
    void foo(int x) {

    }
};
```

But fails to compile for one like this:

```
class A {
public:
    void foo(const int& x) {

    }
};
```

Why is it so (by why I mean why it fails to deduce the type) and how (if it is possible at all) can I make this code work with references?
[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/cTf9B4)

Comment: maybe `Args&&...` and `std::forward`?

Comment: @user3365922 tried it. Feels like solution, doesn't work

Comment: Wouldn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730989/c-template-variadic-templates-pass-by-const-reference) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444159/mixing-pass-by-reference-and-pass-by-value-to-variadic-template-function-valid) help you in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you have conflict deductions for `Args` between:

- `R (T::*fun)(Args...)`
- `Args... args`

I suggest to have more generic code (no duplications between `R (T::*fun)(Args...)` and
 const version `R (T::*fun)(Args...) const` and other alternative) with:

```
template<class T, class F, class... Args>
decltype(auto) call_or_throw(const std::weak_ptr<T>& ptr,
                             const std::string& error,
                             F f,
                             Args&&... args)
{
    if (auto sp = ptr.lock()) 
    {
        return std::invoke(f, *sp, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    else 
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(error.c_str());
    }
}
```

Comment: good point about cv-qualification of member function, I think this is best solution so far

Answer (score 8):

`Args` types cannot be deduced both as `const&` (from `fun` parameter declaration) and non-reference from `args` declaration. A simple fix is to use two separate template type parameter packs:

```
template<class T, class R, class... Args, class... DeclaredArgs>
R call_or_throw(
    const std::weak_ptr<T>& ptr,
    const std::string& error,
    R (T::*fun)(DeclaredArgs...),
    Args... args);
```

As a downside, I can imagine slightly longer error messages in case of bad usage.

Comment: You probably want `Args&&... args`

Answer (score 5):

Note that the template parameter `Args`'s type is deduced as `const int&` on the 3rd function argument `&A::foo`, and deduced as `int` on the 4th function parameter `1`. They don't match and cause deduction fails.

You can exclude the 4th parameter from [deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts), e.g.

```
template<class T, class R, class... Args>
R call_or_throw(const std::weak_ptr<T>& ptr, 
                const std::string& error, 
                R (T::*fun)(Args...), 
                std::type_identity_t<Args>... args) {
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TKm97KGACxqBLVlP)

<sub>PS: [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) is supported since C++20; but it's quite easy to implement one.</sub>

Comment: @bartop I think so. We can make the 4th parameter conforming to forwarding reference style, i.e. `Args&&...`, then put `std::type_identity` on the 3rd parameter like `R (T::*fun)(std::type_identity_t<Args>...)`. [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Z4PucCSFE7bEBVUx) and [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/28thrXnF66UI4mtF)

Comment: @songyuanyo yeah, but then it will break for value argument.

Comment: You can already use forward from your code [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Z4PucCSFE7bEBVUx). It will just do "extra" move.